Docker compose including node js and html
Iam Running a docker compose that has html and mysql and nodejs
mapping mysql 3306:3306 and nodejs 3000:3000
Iam 100% that they are connected throught the same network on the docker compose
When I run the docker-compose up it says that nodejs connected to mysql database and listenning on port 3000
but from my html when i try to fetch it gave me error fetching
Literally tried everything but it's refusing to fetch
here is the error i get when i try to fetch
User
nodejs:3000/addStudent:1 
        
        
        Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
Team.html:114  Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at addStudent (Team.html:102:5)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (Team.html:1:1)  

here is my nodejs `
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:8080', // Replace with your frontend origin
  methods: ['POST'], // Allow only POST requests
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type'], // Allow only Content-Type header
}));


const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'mysql',
  user: 'abdullah',
  password: '123564',
  database: 'maybe',
});
connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error connecting to MySQL:', err);
    process.exit(1); // Exit the application if unable to connect to MySQL
  }
  console.log('Connected to MySQL database!');
});

app.use(express.json());


app.post('/addStudent', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Request body:', req.body);

  const { name, age, cgpa, student_id } = req.body;

  const query = 'INSERT INTO students (name, age, cgpa, student_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
  connection.query(query, [name, age, cgpa, student_id], (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error inserting student into database:', err);
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error inserting student into database' });
      return;
    }
    console.log(`Inserted student with ID: ${results.insertId}`);
    res.json({ message: 'Student added successfully' });
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
});

and here is my docker-composer yml
version: '3.7'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "mainpassword"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "maybe"
      MYSQL_USER: "abdullah"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "123564"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      
    networks:
      - internalnet

  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - mysql # Assuming your Node.js service depends on a MySQL service
    volumes:
      - ./site-content/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./site-content/css:/usr/share/nginx/html/css
      - ./site-content/webfonts:/usr/share/nginx/html/fonts
      - ./site-content/images:/usr/share/nginx/html/images
    
    networks:
      - internalnet

  nodejs:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nodejs
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    expose:
      - 3000
    depends_on:
      - mysql # Assuming your Node.js service depends on a MySQL service
    networks:
      - internalnet

networks:
  internalnet:
    driver: bridge


and this is the fetching method from my html script iam trying to run in the html
   fetch('http://nodejs:3000/addStudent', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ name, age, cgpa, id })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        alert(data.message);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        alert('An error occurred. Please try again.');
    });
}


Your HTML/Javascript code is running in the browser, and it can't see the Docker-internal host names.  In the linked question I detail a couple of paths around this.
